# Restaurar Soft Delete Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo el método store de una clase Size, que usa el validador NewSizesRequest

```
public function store(NewSizesRequest $r) {
    if ($r->ajax()) {
        $this->sizesInterface->store($r->all());

        return response()->json("Mensaje");
    }
}
```

En la clase NewSizeRequest tengo la siguiente regla:

```
  public function rules() {
        return [
            'size' => 'required|numeric|unique:sizes,size'
        ];
    }
```

El problema esta en el siguiente caso:

Agrego un tamaño 'x' a la base de datos. Luego elimino ese registro con SoftDelete. Ahora si yo pongo para agregar de nuevo un tamaño y repito 'x' me dice que ya existe aunque no se muestre por el deleted_at.

No encuentro la forma de hacer que si existe, hacer un $size->restore(), como si lo hubiese creado, pero restaurandolo nomas!

Comment: ¿En qué punto deseas restaurarlo?

Comment: Sinceramente nose, que cuando el validador verifique con la regla Unique que ya existe ese dato, llamar a un metodo del controlador size que sea restore y buscar esa intancia. O si se te ocurre alguna bienvenido sea! @Shaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para estos casos, **Laravel** soporta agregar `wheres` adicionales a tu validación de unique, solo tendrías que agregar `deleted_at,NULL` al final:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'size' => 'required|numeric|unique:sizes,size,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL'
    ];
}
```

Puedes ver la [documentación completa aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)

Luego para restaurar o crear tu objeto puedes usar `updateOrCreate` sobre todos los registros y luego hacer un `restore`

```
$this->sizesInterface->withTrashed()->updateOrCreate(
            ['size' => $r->input('size')],
            $r->all())->restore();
```

No he podido probarlo, pero esa es la idea.

Comment: Pero ahi va controlar que no exista el valor dentro de los campos que el deleted_at no es null, la validación pasa y yo tendria que volver a controlar en el metodo store si el valor existe where deleted_at = null y si existe restaurarlo... funcionaria pero capaz hay otra forma de no estar controlando eso en el método store.

Comment: @JuanPabloB de todas formas al momento de guardar se tiene que preguntar si ya existe actualizarlo, si no crearlo, he actualizado mi respuesta, con una forma relativamente sencilla de realizarlo.

Comment: bien jugado Al-Lee! Saludos hermano, gracias por participar de la comunidad :D